# Send keys to Adobe Report-Builder plugin while saving Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am trying to have VB open Excel, save the workbook (after a macro runs), then close the workbook. The catch is that I have an Adobe Report-Builder Plugin (used to pull Adobe Analytics into the worksheet) that is set to run (via macro) upon the launch of this particular workbook. It wouldnt be a problem except it has its own set of popup-prompts to save the workbook prior to exiting. Thus, when i want the workbook to close i cant use the following code because the Adobe popup/prompt takes focus

```
xlWb.Save
xlWb.Close SaveChanges=True
xl.Quit
```

So I need to send an "enter" key to that active window (to click "yes" to save). So far i have this. Im not sure if the sendkey command is working correctly or whether i need to point that command to the focus/active window.

```
Sub RunMacro()
Set xl   = CreateObject("Excel.application")
Set xlWb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me\Documents\workbook.xlsm")
xl.Application.Visible = True
xl.Application.run "'workbook.xlsm'!RefreshAllReportBuilderRequests"
WScript.Sleep 60000 
xlWb.Close
WScript.Sleep 2000 
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Set xlWb = Nothing
Set xl   = Nothing
Set shell  = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What about `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

Comment: i think the displayAlert must remain because I do need to save the workbook before closing